# PHP href doesn't work

Tags: php, href

I have a href in my php code to edit or remove photos from the site.

```
echo("<a href='photohandling.php?action=1&file=".$iPictureNumber."'><img height='35' src='./pictures/delete.png' border='0' ></a>");
```

But the code only works sometimes. The photohandling.php isn't fired up everytime. I put an echo inside the photohandling.php to see if the file is used. And most of the times it doesn't. Why? Is the code not solled or is this a problem of the browser?

Anyone an idea? 
Thanks in advance.

Edit:
None of the solutions worked thus far. Thanks for thinking along.
But let me further clearify the problem:

href='photohandling.php?action=1&file=2'> then the photohandling.php fires up

href='photohandling.php?action=1&file=3'> then the photohandling.php doesn't work

href='photohandling.php?action=1&file=4'> the photohandling.php fires up

href='photohandling.php?action=1&file=5'> the photohandling.php fires up

The next time only 2 and 5 works, then only the first, then none of them, etc

They are generated by an FOR loop.
Thats whats so puzzling about it, its just a parameter.

And if anyone has an alternative solution to this, please youre welcome. This project has to be done in a couple of weeks.

Comment: Have you tried switching the quote marks? so `'` instead of `"` and vice versa?

Comment: problem might be on some other part.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo "<a href='photohandling.php?action=1&file={$IPictureNumber}'><img height='35'src='./pictures/delete.png' border='0' ></a>";
```

The single quotes mean $IPictureNumber isn't being treated as a variable, so t needs to be enclosed in curly brackets. Also make sure you are poitning the photohandling.php in the right location. If it's in a higher level use "../photohandling.php" etc

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the absolute URL to the file. If it's in your root, try this:

```
echo("<a href='/photohandling.php?action=1&file=".$iPictureNumber."'><img height='35' src='./pictures/delete.png' border='0' ></a>");
```

Otherwise it will append the file to the current URL, so if you're on http://example.com/test, it will try to reach http://example.com/test/photohandling.php.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<a href="../photohandling.php?action=1&file='.$iPictureNumber.'"><img height="35" src="./pictures/delete.png" border="0" >Link Name</a>';
```

Try to use **../** (**dot-dot-slash**) to get into the parent folder and then include file name.

Comment: Or use absolute URL starting with `/` - `/photohandling.php`, if it is on the document root.